# Сайт крашится в Chrome на iPad iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, google-chrome, ipad

Chrome (последний под iPad iOS8.4/iOS9) вылетает либо при загрузке страницы, либо при начале промотки. Никаких ошибок, ничего не вылезает — просто черный экран и выход в главное меню. В Safari под iOS, в Chrome под Android и десктопы/ноутбуки все работает корректно.

Выяснил, что проблема в слайдере — но где конкретно, не понятно. Отключая слайдер полностью проблема решается, оставляя частичную функциональность — нет.

Ссылка на умирающую страницу: mfstest.etera.su/slider.html, код слайдера: http://mfstest.etera.su/assets/lib/dragSlider.js

Comment: тормозят слайдеры, по мне так лучше вообще отказаться от них

Comment: Если указанный слайдер ломает сайт, быть может, имеет смысл заменить его на какой-нибудь [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) или другой, проверявшийся на мобильных устройствах?